# What is responsible for displaying last login information on Debian?

Tags: bash, debian, login

What is responsible for showing last login information on Debian when the user logs in?

By "last login information" I mean this:

```
Last login: Mon Jan 16 18:24:50 2023 from 10.32.0.84
```

I need to display disk free space and maybe something more after user logs in.

Maybe I should put such script in `/etc/profile.d/`

Or maybe I should echo to `/etc/motd`?

Comment: `sshd` is not responsible for printing this line. It comes from the pam module `pam_lastlog`, which is not extensible to include printing other information. If you want something else I suggest putting a script in `/etc/profile.d`.

Comment: Ubuntu has update-motd https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UpdateMotd which generates a dynamic motd on a timer. We have this on our servers at work for displaying things like whether the last puppet run was successful. It's not updated every time someone logs in though, so it's not the right answer if you want the latest information every time you re-login. To run specific commands and display their output every time I log in, I put it in `.bash_profile`